# Elegant way to model multiple reviewers for a form in MVC with Entity First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How would you model  the data on the form where there are multiple reviewers.  Do you create multiple collections or use an array and adding a type field? or something else? When I used multiple instances as commented out, it created multiple MainForm_id in the employee table.

//main form

```
public class MainForm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee[]> EmployeeArray { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Employee> EmployeeReviewing { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Employee> EmployeeSupervisor { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Employee> EmployeeManager { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Employee> EmployeeBigBoss { get; set; }

}
```

//employee

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProgramEntryId { get; set; }
    public int ReviewerTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual MainForm MainForm { get; set; }
    public virtual ReviewerType ReviewerType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not store the collections directly on the MainForm class. Instead I would have a new class that houses both an employeeId and a formId.

///Form

```
public class MainForm
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

///Employee

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeType")]
    public int EmployeeTypeId {get;set;}

}
```

///EmployeeType

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

///EmployeeReview

```
public class EmployeeReview
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MainForm ")]
    public int MainFormId{ get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual MainForm MainForm { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would simply query your form such that:

```
var reviews = EmployeeReview.Where(x => x.Employee.EmployeeTypeId ==
(int)Enum.Employee.EmployeeSupervisor)
```

reviews  at this point would grant you access to the required form and employees of said type who reviewed the form.